# Run Time Error in Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, runtime, runtime-error

This week, i had been experiencing a run time error that forces visual studio to close unexpectedly. Though most of my codes are saved, it is still troublesome.

How do I avoid it?

[image]

Comment: Make sure you have latest Operating System update and then update Visual Studio (if any latest update pending). Restart the machine and see if that helps.

Comment: Hi! I observed that this error happens when I am manually adjusting gridviews in an html table. As of now, it is still really annoying and troublesome.